# Add Item and stay in current page

Tags: php

I have this code to prosses the ADD TO CART button:

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
} else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                  // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                  array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                  $wasFound = true;
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
       } // close foreach loop
       if ($wasFound == false) {
           array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
       }
}
exit();
}
```

And my add button:

```
<form id="bd_itm1" name="bd_itm1" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'. $id . '" />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>
```

When I click it it takes me to the cart.php as I tell it to do with my header(location).
But I do not want it to. I want to stay at the same page as my ad button.
Now, if I remove my header(location) it takes me to a blank page. (but still it adds the item to cart)
No errors in my logs. FOR SURE. :)

Many are saying things about ajax and jquery... but I am not that familiar with these!

Thank you

My dynamicList code: (I don't know what's happening but just now it showed me your question)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='body' ORDER BY id ASC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
// count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
        $i=0;
        $dynamicListBody = '<table width: 90%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; color: #00E6AA;>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $dynamicListBody .= ($i==0) ? '<tr>':'';
        $dynamicListBody .= '<td width="10%">
                    <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../stock_photos/' . $id . '.png" height="80px" width="40px" alt="' . $product_name . '" />
                     </td>
                     <td width="35%">
                    <span class=itmttl>' . $product_name . '</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class=text>' . $details . '
                    <br />
                    €' . $price . '</span>
                    <br />
                      <form name="bd_itm" id="bd_itm" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="' . $id . '" />
                    <input type="submit" name="button' . $id . '" id="button' . $id . '" value="Add to Cart" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                      </form>
                     </td>';
        $dynamicListBody .= ($i==1) ? '</tr>':'';
        $i++;
        ($i==2) ? $i=0:'';
        }
        $dynamicListBody.='</table>';
        } else {
            $dynamicListBody = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
            }
        mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You need some AJAX on your site to handle this. There's a few million examples of such things on this site and around the net. Try Googling.

Comment: `but I am not that familiar with these` - It's well worth reading about and experimenting with, as Marc has mentioned, there are countless examples, tutorials, snippets, libraries, etc. that deal with AJAX or jQuery. I doubt very highly that someone wants to flesh out an entire tutorial here when the info is so readily available by searching for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the page refreshing after the POST from your button you could add a redirect in your php code to bring you back to the page the button is on.

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/button/page.php');
exit();
```

You'll have to use AJAX if you want the page not to refresh.

with jquery:

```
$(':submit').click(function() {
    var keyValues = {
        pid : $(this).parent().find('input[name="pid"]').val()
    };
    $.post('help_scripts/cart_functions.php', keyValues, function(rsp) {
        // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
        // rsp will be the response
    });
    return false; // so the page doesn't POST
});
```

put the above javascript in a .js file that is loaded with your button page.

You may want to make this change in your php that runs when the button is pressed:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
```

Change the above to

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1);
```

this is the code that runs if the cart array is not set or is empty

Comment: Marc & Wesley I am searching the web... I am not that lazy :) But the examples, are so many and DIFFERENT that they can give you hard time. I am playing around... <br /> jonathan, I tried the code, but same issue... Blank page. Something that I think I should had mentioned before... I get my items table including my ADD button, through <?php echo $variable ?> I don't know if this is the issue now, BUT I know that when using this it doesn't accept css style, so maybe it doesn't accept your code?

Comment: Ah... my mistake... The code works, but only for my first item listed... All the rest are giving the blank page. Is it the reason above that creates the problem?

Comment: it only works for the first item listed (probably) because your ids are not unique. the jquery gets the val for the input with id 'pid'. make sure your inputs ids are unique and figure out a way to get those ids when the button is clicked for each item. make sense?

Comment: It does make sense BUT I am using a dynamicList to display the items... How am I coing to give unique ids to the button???

Comment: @Jonathan Mayhak I am trying to use id="pid_' . $id . '" (how should I change this: $pid = $_POST['pid'] )but getting them unique it doesn't seem to change anything! Any other option?

Comment: My friend, This edit made the trick not to redirect me to anywhere, if I click any item's add-to-cart button. Thank you for that. BUt since the few last days I discovered that my items are not added to my cart exept of the first one. Which I am trying to solve. Even when they were added and sending me to a blank page when I tested on ff it didn't add them. Only ie was adding them. Is this a jq promblem or my php files???

Comment: use firebug or some javascript console in another browser to see what the parameters are in the POST done by clicking the add to cart button. Make sure the pid is changing when different buttons are clicked. If they are not changing, then your dynamicList code is not creating a unique pid for each item.

Comment: I did, but it gives me undefined variables error when trying to add item. Most likely because the whole code that ADDs REMOVEs & Output the Cart... Is all connected....

Comment: @Jonathan Can you give me a help on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239641/items-not-added-to-my-cart)? I don't know why nobody is answering. Thank you.