# Add Item and stay in current page - php, ajax, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using google translator, so errors may occur.

**My problem:** add Item and stay in current page

I tried to use the advice from the link below but I did not succeed :-(

[Add Item and stay in current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129706/add-item-and-stay-in-current-page#)

**Script code:**

```
    <?php 
if( !defined( 'CUSTOMER_PAGE' ) )
  exit;
require_once DIR_SKIN.'_header.php'; // include design of header
?>
<div id="product">
<?php
if( isset( $aData['sName'] ) ){ // displaying product content ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sTitle = "<?php echo $aData['sName']; ?>";
    var fPrice = Math.abs( "<?php echo $aData['mPrice']; ?>" );
  </script><?php

  if( isset( $aData['mPrice'] ) || isset( $aData['sAvailable'] ) ){ // displaying box with price, basket and availability - START
    echo '<div id="box">';
      if( isset( $aData['mPrice'] ) && is_numeric( $aData['mPrice'] ) ){?>
        <div id="price"><em><?php echo $lang['Price']; ?>:</em><strong id="priceValue"><?php echo $aData['sPrice']; ?></strong><span><?php echo $config['currency_symbol']; ?></span></div><?php
      }
      elseif( !empty( $aData['mPrice'] ) ){?>
        <div id="noPrice"><?php echo $aData['sPrice']; ?></div><?php
      }
      if( isset( $aData['sAvailable'] ) ){?>
        <div id="available"><?php echo $aData['sAvailable']; ?></div><?php
      }
      if( isset( $aData['mPrice'] ) && is_numeric( $aData['mPrice'] ) && !empty( $config['basket_page'] ) && isset( $oPage->aPages[$config['basket_page']] ) ){?>
        <form action="<?php echo $oPage->aPages[$config['basket_page']]['sLinkName']; ?>" method="post" id="addBasket" class="form">
          <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo $lang['Basket_add']; ?></legend>
            <input type="hidden" name="iProductAdd" value="<?php echo $aData['iProduct']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="iQuantity" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['Basket_add']; ?>" class="submit" />
          </fieldset>
        </form><?php
      }
    echo '</div>';
  } // displaying box with price, basket and availability - END
}
?>
</div>
```

I've rewritten the code and added it below:

```
if( isset( $aData['sName'] ) ){ // displaying product content ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#addBasket .submit').click(function() {
    var keyValues = {
        iProductAdd : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iProductAdd"]').val(),
        iQuantity : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iQuantity"]').val()
    };
    $.post('<?php echo $oPage->aPages[$config['basket_page']]['sLinkName']; ?>', keyValues, function(rsp) {
        // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
        // rsp will be the response
    });
    return false; // so the page doesn't POST
});
  </script>
```

But still does not work, after clicking the button, the product is added but we do not stay on the same page and go to the basket.

I will be grateful for any help

Adam

Comment: Instead of `$('#addBasket .submit')` try with `$('#addBasket').on('submit, function(){...`

Comment: looks like you are putting the script before the form and the button doesn't exist at that point so the event listener never gets added to it.  Wrap in `$(function() { /* your code*/})`

Comment: updated answer can you try that ...

Comment: `$(function() { $("#addBasket").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` instead of return false;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#addBasket .submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keyValues = {
        iProductAdd : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iProductAdd"]').val(),
        iQuantity : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iQuantity"]').val()
    };
    $.post('<?php echo $oPage->aPages[$config['basket_page']]['sLinkName']; ?>', keyValues, function(rsp) {
        // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
        // rsp will be the response
    });

});
```

**Edit 1:**

You can do one more thing.  Instead of having input type as `submit`. keep it as `button` as I noticed you are making JSON manually.

So your input submit can be something like this

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $lang['Basket_add']; ?>" class="submit" />
```

Comment: They basically do the same thing. If `return false` not working something else is probably wrong

Comment: clicking on the button does not cause anything, it does not add to the basket, it does not go any further. :-(

Comment: can you pring keyValues in console and see if JSON is created

Comment: `$(function() { $("#addBasket").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }); });`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
$('#addBasket .submit').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
var keyValues = {
    iProductAdd : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iProductAdd"]').val(),
    iQuantity : $(this).parent().find('input[name="iQuantity"]').val()
};
$.post('<?php echo $oPage->aPages[$config['basket_page']]['sLinkName']; ?>', keyValues, function(rsp) {
    // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
    // rsp will be the response
});
return false; // so the page doesn't POST
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, he adds to the cart and goes to his basket-site, does not remain on the product.

Comment: ``$(function() { $("#addBasket").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }); });``

Answer (score 0):

The event listener is not being added to the button because the button doesn't exist when the script tag is above the form

Either put the script tag after the form or wrap the code in *"ready"* a call

```
$(function(){
  $('#addBasket .submit').click(function() {
  ...
})
```

Comment: I used the advice "looks like you are putting on the listener in the future. Wrap in $ (function () {/ * your code * /}) - charlietfl 12 mins ago. "

It worked :-)

but I still have a small problem, until I refresh my browsers, I have 0 products in the basket.

Comment: Please!! : `$(function() { $("#addBasket").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }); });`

Comment: It works but I still have a small problem, until I refresh my browser manually, or do not switch to a different page, I have 0 products in the basket.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to make sure what is sent is what you expect and check status of request and what is actually returned